# Facebook Payment Error "Something went wrong while processing your payment. You haven't been charged for this transaction, so please try again."

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've seen this error message posted in a number of places, but none of the solutions posted are getting me past it.  I've tested payments with my own account (listed as a payment tester in the application) and with my test users and I always get the pop-up with the above error.  I have the following code to call the payment dialog:

```
 function buyPack() {
    FB.ui({
        method: 'pay',
        action: 'purchaseitem',
        product: 'https://localhost:44304/html/buypack.html'
    },
 function (data) {
       alert(data);
   }
);
}
```

data is always null on callback after I close the dialog.

My "product" html file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head prefix=
     "og: http://ogp.me/ns# 
      fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# 
      product: http://ogp.me/ns/product#">
    <meta property="og:type"                   content="og:product" />
    <meta property="og:title"                  content="2012 Pack" />
    <meta property="og:image"           content="https://localhost:44304/Images/Logo5050.png" /> 
    <meta property="og:description"            content="5 cards from the 2012 set" />
    <meta property="og:url"               content="https://localhost:44304/HTML/BuyPack.html" />
    <meta property="product:price:amount"      content="1"/>
    <meta property="product:price:currency"    content="USD"/>
</head>
</html>
```

This is pulled almost verbatim from the Facebook tutorial.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?  Anything I should check?  I'm able to consistently do other facebook interactions (getting user information, inviting friends, etc) without issue.  Help, please!  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you a "payment tester" and administrator/developer/owner at the same time? Had problems with this myself and used a different fb account as "payment tester".